# Populate PictureBox from ListView items

Tags: vb.net, listview, datagridview, populate

Hello everyone i need a little help. I want to populate my `PictureBox` `picpreview` from `ListView` but it says `NotSupportedException was unhandled The given path's format is not supported`.The textbox seems to be working fine but i got stuck at retrieving my image file. By the way the image is .gif

```
 Dim sql As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader

Dim inc As Integer
Dim listselect As String
Private Sub get_data()
    Try
        lvroutine.Items.Clear()
        connection()
        sql = "SELECT * From tblprogram ORDER BY MUSCLEGROUP ASC"
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read
            Dim lv As ListViewItem = lvroutine.Items.Add(dr("MUSCLEGROUP"))

            With lv.SubItems

                .Add(dr("EXERCISENAME"))
                .Add(dr("EQUIPMENT"))
                .Add(dr("PREVIEW"))

            End With
        End While
        con.Close()


    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Try
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub view_record()

    connection()

    listselect = lvroutine.SelectedItems.Item(0).Text

    sql = "SELECT * From tblprogram WHERE MUSCLEGROUP ='" & listselect & "'"
    cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read Then
        txtmuscle.Text = dr("MUSCLEGROUP")
        editprogram.txtexname.Text = dr("EXERCISENAME")
        editprogram.txteq.Text = dr("EQUIPMENT")
        picpreview = dr("PREVIEW")


    End If
End Sub

Private Sub clientprogram_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Call get_data()
    Call connection()

    sql = "Select * From tblprogram ORDER BY MUSCLEGROUP ASC"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)

    da.Fill(ds, "tblprogram")

    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub lvroutine_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lvroutine.Click
    txtmuscle.Text = lvroutine.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(0).Text
    txtexercise.Text = lvroutine.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(1).Text
    txtequipment.Text = lvroutine.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(2).Text
    'picpreview.Image = Image.FromFile(lvroutine.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).ToString)<--- This is where the error is.

End Sub




End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your path is the right path. Sometimes die Visual Studio throws this up. Just set a Breakpoint or open a MsgBox before executing the line of code (the line where the error appears) and take a look at it.

Secondly, you can try to load in in an Bitmap:

```
picpreview.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(lvroutine.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).ToString)
```

Also, i'm not 100% sure but isn't `.ToString` a methode? I came from the C# world but i'm think you have to add braces after `.ToString`:

```
picpreview.Image = Bitmap.FromFile(lvroutine.SelectedItems(0).SubItems(3).ToString**()**)
```

Give it a try and let me hear whats worked or, if so, did not worked.